# How do I manipulate my pandas dataframe to transpose multiple columns per row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I have a pandas dataframe with columns (A, B), and 3 columns of type (X, Y). A, B, X, and Y are always values. Example is attached (Table 1 without the red text).  Note this is synthetic and shorter data to my real table, which has over 50 (X, Y) columns.

[image]

| (A, B) | (X1, Y1) | (X2, Y2) | (X3,Y3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (22, 3) | 4.33 | 3.45 | 11.12 |
| (23, 4) | 5.23 | 5.65 | 12.23 |
| (27, 3) | 4.66 | 13.45 | 12.34 |
| (42, 5) | 7.44 | 12.32 | 1.23 |

I want to transform it to this 2nd table (Table 2 with the red text), where the 3 (X, Y) columns are 'rotated' into a single column. To do this, essentially the 3 (X, Y) columns need to be rotated for each (A, B) row, which means each (A, B) row needs to be duplicated for the 3 (X, Y) column - how do I do this in python please?

[image]

| (A, B) | (X, Y) |
| --- | --- |
| (22, 3) | 4.33 |
| (22, 3) | 3.45 |
| (22, 3) | 11.12 |
| (23, 4) | 5.23 |
| (23, 4) | 5.65 |
| (23, 4) | 12.23 |
| (27, 3) | 4.66 |
| (27, 3) | 13.45 |
| (27, 3) | 12.34 |
| (42, 5) | 7.44 |
| (42, 5) | 12.32 |
| (42, 5) | 1.23 |

I have tried the below .transpose code but it did not give me what I need.

```
df.transpose()
```

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example _as text_ ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) together with [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). Or second approach with [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html?highlight=melt#pandas.DataFrame.melt). The second one is just sorted differently by default.

```
df.set_index('(A, B)').stack().droplevel(1).reset_index(name='(X, Y)')
```

```
     (A, B)  (X, Y)
0   (22, 3)    4.33
1   (22, 3)    3.45
2   (22, 3)   11.12
3   (23, 4)    5.23
4   (23, 4)    5.65
5   (23, 4)   12.23
6   (27, 3)    4.66
7   (27, 3)   13.45
8   (27, 3)   12.34
9   (42, 5)    7.44
10  (42, 5)   12.32
11  (42, 5)    1.23
```

or something like this:

```
df.melt(id_vars='(A, B)', value_vars=df.filter(regex='X|Y').columns, value_name='(X, Y)').drop('variable',axis=1)
```